# Is it possible to create daily budget alerts in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

Currently, I have monthly budget alerts set up in Google Cloud Platform (GCP) that we are using along with Pub/Sub notifications integrated with Slack and MS Teams. However, for more granular cost management, I am attempting to set up daily budget alerts.

I've tried setting up daily budget but it seems that GCP allows budget setting only for "Monthly", "Quarterly", "Yearly", and custom time ranges with specific, constant, dates.

Does GCP offer the functionality to set up a daily budget or is there any other way around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching through the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues), I checked that on October 14th, 2021 a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) for creating a daily budget alert in addition to monthly, quarterly, and yearly options was created. You can check its status [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/202986253).

Although there's already a specialized team working and evaluating the request, please, take into account that they can't provide you with an E.T.A and there isn't any guarantee that this feature request will be deployed.

In addition to this, if you would like to improve the issue's visibility, please, click on the "+1" button located at the top right side of the webpage, sharing that you are impacted.